# search words in cells in columns if not found error

Tags: excel, vba

i am trying to search for list of words in different combos and can include commas(i.e john, sue, [john,sue]) also is not case sensitive when looking for the words. code is below how would search multiple words and also not make it case sensitive and if there are words other then those listed error message

```
Sub Search_Range_For_Text()
Dim c As Range
Dim alastrow As Long
Dim ContainWord As String
ContainWord = "Claim"

alastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For Each c In Range("A2:B2" & alastrow)
       If c.Find(ContainWord) Is Nothing And c.Value <> "" Then
        
         MsgBox "Word found  " & c.Address
         End If
         Next c
  
End Sub
```

Comment: use the other arguments in the [`Range.Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find)

Comment: If you just want to look at each specific cell, then use `InStr` and skip using `Find`. Or use `Find` and remove the loop.

Comment: @ScottCraner would i take out the containword or include it like this   If c.Find(ContainWord, tree, car) Is Nothing And c.Value <> "" Then

Comment: @BigBen sorry im confused i would to loop because im looking through each cell in the entire column to make sure those listed word are only ones present  pls help

Comment: Then use `InStr`.

Comment: @BigBen sorry im new to vba wouldn't that just give the positions of the string only?

Comment: You can test if the result is `>0`, if so, the string was "found"

Comment: @BigBen would this be the right syntax it does not seem to work                                    Sub SubstringCheck()
Dim MainString As String
Dim c As Range
Dim alastrow As Long

MainString = "claim"

For Each c In Range("A2:B2" & alastrow)
If c.Text(InStr(LCase(MainString))) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Word found  " & c.Address
End If
Next c
End Sub

Comment: Please see the [`InStr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function) documentation, or similar examples on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Couple issues with the code in your comment:

1. You should declare a worksheet variable to avoid relying on the `ActiveSheet`
2. Your range `"A2:B2" & alastrow` is not correct. When `alastrow = 50` you will end up with `A2:B250`
3. The right syntax of `InStr` for your purposes is `InStr( Cell to search, value to search for, comparison type`)
4. Use comparison type `vbTextCompare` which is not case sensitive i.e. `A = a`

---

```
Sub substring()

Dim Target As String, C As Range, lr As Long, ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
lr = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Target = "Claim"

For Each C In Range("A2:B" & lr)
    If InStr(C, Target, Compare:=vbTextCompare) Then
        MsgBox C.Address
    End If
Next C

End Sub
```

---

You don't necessary need to check if the test value is larger than 0. In solution, the test string will be evaluated such that `0 = FALSE` and `ELSE = TRUE`

Comment: im getting a 'Object doesn't support named arguments' error also can i add multiple values to Target ? ie Target= "Claims" , "Tree", "house"?

Comment: also issue is when i have words (i.e claim,tree or tree,claim) those should pass test , i just want error msgbox when listed values in any combo with (,) are not present